# Displaying time in minutes/hours/days using Carbon or any other tools

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I want to convert date to make it like, if i posted comment 2 minutes ago it will show 2 minutes ago, if 2 hours ago, like that, week ago, and so on

```
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <p class="text-secondary text-center">{{ $comment->created_at }}</p>
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use diffForHumans()

```
$comment->created_at->diffForHumans();
```

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `diffForHumans()`, which is a `Carbon` method for returning a date relative to now. On `Model` instances, like your `Comment` class, the attribute `created_at` should already be converted to a `Carbon` instance, so you can simply call:

```
{{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
```

This should return something similar to `1 hour ago`, `5 months ago`, etc. See https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff for full details.